# Sqlplus install on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sqlplus

I wanted to install SQLPlus on my Ubuntu. I followed this instructions:

http://gm.matias.ph/running-oracles-sql-plus-in-linux-ubuntu-2010-08-04

I downloaded .rpm packages and installed alien, but then trying to unpack .rpm files (point 5), I got error:

> "Unpacking of 'oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.i386.rpm'
>   failed at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package/Rpm.pm line 168."

What to do to solve it? I am newbie, please help.

Comment: Without knowing what is happening around line 168, I would guess that you might be hitting a wall in Security. Who are you unpacking as??

Comment: As root. I typed "sudo alien -k instantclient*.rpm".

Answer (score 1):

Just hit this one - running alien on packages on CIFS (samba).  I think there are symlinks in there.  I have cpio & rpm2cpio, the two commands run in a pipe in RPM.pm..... of course you can't create symlinks in CIFS mounted filesystems!

I copied the files to local disk & Bob's your uncle.

/Bill

Answer (score 0):

With Alien you need to install a few helper files and then convert the .rpm to a .deb file and then install using dpkg. Like this:

Install the Alien dev tools and helper files

```
xxx@ubuntuorg$ sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
```

Then you should convert your .rpm to a .deb package like this

```
xxx@ubuntuorg$ sudo alien packagename.rpm
```

Then you're going to do something like this with the .deb package you just created.

xxx@ubuntuorg$ sudo dpkg packagename.deb

Lastly, Alien does not always convert the package or perform the install correctly. If this also fails please post your RPM.pm file, lines 150 to 175.